# Почему read() принимает количество байт с помощью знакового типа?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

`std::ifstream::read(char_type*, std::streamsize)` принимает количество читаемых байт с помощью знакового типа `std::streamsize`, а `std::fread(void*, std::size_t, std::size_t, std::FILE*)` -- с помощью беззнакового типа `std::size_t`. При этом во многих примерах и там и там для количества байт используют `sizeof`, который выдаёт результат в `std::size_t`. Размер `std::vector<char>` тоже беззнаковый. Так почему тогда эта функция принимает знаковый тип? Как правильно кастовать типы, чтобы без проблем заполнить вектор байтов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, правильный ответ - так сложилось исторически. Вначале в си/с++ использовали активно int для всего (в старом си это вообще был "тип по умолчанию"). То, что какие то файлы будут больше 2 Гигабайт даже никто не думал ("это громадные размеры") - сейчас так думают о 2 в 64. Плюс, оказалась очень удобно использовать отрицательные числа как признак ошибки. Тот же read/[recv](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=recv&category=2&russian=0) возвращает положительное число, если что то прочитали, ноль - если файл/сокет был закрыт и отрицательное, если ошибка. Удобно же.

Но потом математики посмотрели на это и говорят "ну как размер массива может быть отрицательным?" Плюс это приводит к ошибкам, когда пытаемся сложить два размера массива, а один из них отрицательный (потому что это на самом деле было кол-во прочитанных байт с ошибкой). И решено было, что оптимально будет хранить в беззнаковом типе, а ошибку возвращать другим способом (например, исключением или кодом возврата). Но не все пошли этим путем, в java беззнаковых типов нет (или уже появлялись?).

Но даже в таком случае многие не хотели отказываться от привычной -1 для ошибок. В плюсах куча мест, где используется 0xFFF...FF для индикации именно ошибки, что иногда вызывает прикольные баги (попытка выделить такое кол-во памяти обычно ничем хорошим не заканчивается).

Потом умные дядьки с комитета стандартизации ещё раз посмотрели и решили, хватит притворятся и давайте добавим [ssize](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r1.html) - он такой же как size, но только знаковый. Там есть интересные вещи, которые объясняют, зачем это всё нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Тип `std :: streamsize` - это целочисленный тип со знаком, используемый для представления количества символов, переданных в операции ввода-вывода, или размера буфера ввода-вывода. Он используется как подписанный аналог `std :: size_t`, аналогично типу POSIX `ssize_t`.

За исключением конструкторов `std :: strstreambuf`, отрицательные значения `std :: streamsize` никогда не используются

В проекте стандарта C ++ есть следующая сноска 296 в разделе 27.5.2 Типы, в которой говорится:

`streamsize` используется в большинстве мест, где ISO C будет использовать `size_t`. В большинстве случаев `streamsize` может использовать `size_t`, за исключением конструкторов `strstreambuf`, которые требуют отрицательных значений. Вероятно, это должен быть знаковый тип, соответствующий `size_t` (это то, что Posix.2 называет `ssize_t`).

И мы видим, что в разделе **D.7.1.1** конструкторы `strstreambuf` у нас есть следующие записи:

```
strstreambuf(char* gnext_arg, streamsize n, char *pbeg_arg = 0);
strstreambuf(signed char* gnext_arg, streamsize n,
   signed char *pbeg_arg = 0);
strstreambuf(unsigned char* gnext_arg, streamsize n,
   unsigned char *pbeg_arg = 0);
```

и говорится:

`gnext_arg` должен указывать на первый элемент объекта массива, количество элементов N которого определяется следующим образом:

И из следующего обсуждения мы можем увидеть, что n, имеющее тип `streamsize`, действительно требуется, чтобы иметь возможность принимать отрицательное значение:

> - Если n> 0, N равно n.
> - Если n == 0, N равно `std :: strlen (gnext_arg)`.
> - Если n <0, N равно INT_MAX.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что это за тип, а почему он знаковый, когда всё остальное API использует беззнаковые типы, и как использовать знаковый и беззнаковый типы вместе при чтении

Comment: @juice, исправил ответ на более точный

Comment: Как прочитать вектор байтов? Если его размер в `std::size_t`, то он может не вместиться в `std::streamsize`

Comment: @juice , Если Вы перейдёте к определнию типов, Вы увидите, что `std::streamsize` имеет тип `long long`, а `std::size_t` имеет тип `unsigned int`, следовательно не может возникнуть ситуации, которую Вы описали

Comment: Они зависят от реализации, у меня оба 64битные

Comment: "подписанный тип" ? гугл транслятор? размер `std::size_t` определяется самым компилятором. К тому же, у меня прям сейчас `sizeof(std::size_t) == 8`

Answer (score 1):

Как так вышло, что тип `std::streamsize` является знаковым целочисленным типом, судить не стану, однако, замечу, что даже если бы он был беззнаковым, то основную вашу проблему — "правильное преобразование типов" — это бы никак не решило.

Стандарт языка **НЕ гарантирует**, что

1. Все значения типа `std::size_t` представимы типом `std::streamsize`,
2. Все неотрицательные значения типа `std::streamsize` представимы типом `std::size_t`,
3. Размер вектора `std::vector<some_type>` представим типом `std::streamsize`,
4. Любое значение типа `std::streamsize` представимо типом `std::vector<some_type>::difference_type`
5. Любое значение типа `std::size_t` представимо типом `std::vector<some_type>::size_type`.

Таким образом, для полной уверенности, что при преобразовании значения одного типа в значение другого типа не произойдёт неожиданного усечения, следует перед преобразованием проверить, поместится ли преобразуемое значение в целевой тип.

Например, явно:

```
if ( char_vect.size() <= static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()) )
    fout.write(&char_vect[0], char_vect.size());
```

Или даже так:

```
static_assert( std::numeric_limits<std::vector<char>::difference_type>::max() <= std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
```

---

Максимальное количество элементов в векторе, между прочим, ограниченно сверху максимальным значением некоторого **знакового** целочисленного типа `std::vector<some_type>::difference_type`. Это обусловлено тем, что метод `max_size()` возвращает значение, равное значению `distance(​begin(), end())` для некоторого максимально большого возможного вектора. См.: [container.requirements.general/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#4). А `std::distance` возвращает значение знакового целочисленного типа `difference_type`.